# How can I change the FontFamily Property in all Controls in Windows Forms Application?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I've been searching here for a way to change only the FontFamily of all Controls in my Windows Forms App. Note that I don't want to change their font sizes.

Here's the situation: To promote cross-Windows compatibility, and yet, create good UI, the FontFamily in pre-Vista computers will have one font (Tahoma) and newer versions will work with Open Sans, from Google (the Open Sans font will be distributed with the project).

I've managed to change the fonts in older versions of Windows using the *Environment.OSVersion* property and creating an *Application Setting (UserFont)* on my Form1. Like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major == 5)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.UserFont = new Font("Tahoma", 12);
    }
    else if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.UserFont = new Font("Open Sans", 12);
    }
}
```

So, when the form loads, it changes all child controls to Tahoma or Open Sans, but it also changes the font size to 12. That leads to my question:

How can I change only the FontFamily of all Controls in the form keeping their size and styles?

P.S.: I thought of create several Application Settings for all the font sizes that I'll work with, but I really want a more simple solution.

Thank you :)

Comment: It doesn't work if you set the form's Font.Name property? Don't the controls inherit that setting?

Comment: Hmm, no, this isn't going to work on modern Windows versions.  If you want to use a non-standard font then you'll have to bundle it with your installer.  Problem solved.

Comment: Hans, the Open Sans font will be distributed with the software. The problem is the poor-quality render of Open Sans in Windows XP. To override that, the default font for XP will be Tahoma.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and what I did is just simple like this, with a couple of code lines:

- In design, set the `Open Sans` as the initial font for your main form/window
  (also, you should set all children controls to inherit their parents' font).
- In code, first check the OS version:

  ```
  if (!IsWinVistaOrHigher) {
      this.Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12);
  }
  ```

  and all the children will be automatically inherited. If `false`, the `Open Sans` is loaded as if nothing's ever happened.
- If there is just a few controls with fonts to be modified, the sample code below can keep their original font sizes:

  ```
  label1.Font = new Font("Tahoma", label1.Font.Size);
  label2.Font = new Font("Tahoma", label2.Font.Size);
  ```
- If there are lots of font sizes to be changed, just loop through controls and set the font. The key here is the use of `controlName.Font.Size`, and you can adjust by `controlName.Font.Size - 1`

For further dig-in, the beneath code might help you to get more ideas:

Consider you're drop all controls in a Panel/ TableLayoutPanel/ FlowLayoutPanel, then the loop might be like this:

```
foreach (Control c in FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls) {
    if (c.Controls != null) {
        c.Font = new Font("Tahoma", c.Font.Size)
    }
}
```

In general, a loop procedure could help:

```
public void SetAllControlsFont(ControlCollection ctrls) {
    foreach(Control c in ctrls) {
        if(c.Controls != null) {
            SetAllControlsFont(c.Controls);
        }
        c.Font = new Font("Tahoma", c.Font.Size);
    }
}
```

Then call it in `Form1_Load()` event by: `SetAllControlsFont(this.Controls);`

Note that the code might not work for lack of convert/cast type, but I hope you've got the general idea. Just comment here and I will come back.